# Laravel Queue affecting the execution time of API function

Tags: laravel, jobs, laravel-queue

I have an API function that stores pdf file to my `s3 bucket` and then sends email with the pdf file as an attachment.

Since this is my first time, I got confused because from what I understood, jobs executes from the background, thus, it should not affect the execution time of the function.

But instead, having these jobs makes the execution time almost `8 seconds`.

Here's my function

```
    $is_exist = CoachingApplication::where('user_id', $userID)->first();

    if ($is_exist == null) {
        $application = new CoachingApplication();
        $application->user_id = $userID;
        $application->applicant_name = $applicantName;
        $application->attachment = $filename;
        $application->instrument_rate = $instrumentRate;

        if ($application->save()) {
            if ($filename !== 'none') {
                StoreBucketJob::dispatch($userID, $filename, $attachment_fileArray)->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
            }
            SendEmailJob::dispatch($userID, $userName, $userSlug, $userEmail, $filename)->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
        }
    }
```

If I remove these jobs, the function's execution time is `469ms`.

Any idea why these jobs affects the api's execution time?

Comment: What queue driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the queue driver is setup to `sync` and you are probably using it.

This queue driver means your jobs will be executed within the current process and will not be dispatched in an actual queue (which is pretty useful during development).

A good way to be 100% sure that your job are indeed executed synchronously would be to just put a `dd("ok");` at the first line of the `handle` method inside your job. `handle` is only executed when the job runs, not when it is dispatched.

The queue driver can be updated by editing your `.env` file (look for `QUEUE_CONNECTION`).

There are many queue drivers available and some requires additional dependencies, so you should check out the documentation available https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues.